# Get-EventLog Message Getting a line

Tags: powershell, event-log

I was wondering if there is a way to grab information out of the message from `Get-EventLog`. So far I am using this line of code to get the message:

```
(Get-EventLog -Logname Security -InstanceId 4625 -Newest 1).Message
```

This is will pull the message from an instance ID of 4625, but the whole message. I would like to grab: `Account Name` (2nd one), `Account Domain` (2nd one), and `Workstation Name`.

Here is a display when the command is run:

[image]

The highlighted areas are the things I want to display back. It can be all at once or just issuing a different command for each highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Use [regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) to extract the information from the message. Example for extracting account and domain name:

```
$msg = (Get-EventLog ...).Message

$re = 'Logon Failed:[\s\S]+?Account Name:\s+(.*)\s+Account Domain:\s+(.*)'
if ($msg -match $re) {
  $account = $matches[1]
  $domain  = $matches[2]
}
```

`$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]` refer to the two capturing groups (`(.*)`) in the expression.

The workstation name can be extracted with a similar expression.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: output is as a string so the following would not work:

Does `| select-object` work? I've not used this cmdlet and cannot test my answer.

So your full line could be:

`(Get-EventLog -Logname Security -InstanceId 4625 -Newest 1).message | select-object AccountName,DomainName`

**EDIT CONT**

Ansgar beat me to suggesting expressions. Apologies about the confusion. Lack of knowledge on my part.

Comment: Eventlog messages are strings, so this can't possibly work.

Comment: Apologies, I'll amend the above.